# "Live with every day"

Tags: prepositions, sentence-meaning

In this quotation:

> Strange counterfactuals emerge in Vaughan’s tale, as a result of the very real disparities ***we live with every day***. ([Context](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2016/dec/21/y-the-last-man-by-brian-k-vaughan-and-pia-guerra-a-dystopia-built-by-women))

What does "live with every day" mean? Can I use another preposition here? (live on/in every day)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To “**live with** something” means to “accept something” or to “abide something”.

> live with something
>   (ACCEPT)
>   to experience and accept an unpleasant event, decision, or situation:
>   *When you get arthritis at your age, it’s just something you just have to live with.*
>   —[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/live-with-something)

The words **every day** can be deleted without changing the meaning of the sentence.   They just mean the situation is **continuous** and unlikely to change.

“**Live with**” is a *phrasal verb*.  If you delete “with”, it changes the meaning of the sentence.

Finally, if you delete “every day,” you’ll notice that the sentence ends with “live with” — a preposition at the end of the sentence.  This is a good example of when it’s perfectly fine to end a sentence with a preposition.   The writer may have used “every day” to avoid that occurring.